# Select_tag login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have a drop down menu with a list of all the user names in the db.  From there, I would like the user to choose his/her name and be able to click login and be taken to their respective page.  At this point, a password is not needed. Currently, I have the following:

controller:

```
def login
  @user = User.new
  @users = User.all

  # @user = User.find_by_id(:id)
  # redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: '/login', html: {method: 'get'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Name" %>
  <br/>
    <%= select_tag :user, options_for_select(@users) do |users| %>
      <%= link_to users.name, users %>
    <% end %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <%= f.submit 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

I cannot seem to link the user to their path and also, i want to show the users name in the drop down menu. Currently, it shows a hexidecimal pointer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `select_tag` with a `do`? I never see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be making a new User object here: you just want to load one out of the database.  What you want to do in the controller is just to set `current_user` to be one of the existing users, right?

Also you've got the form submitting back to the action which loads the form in, which seems weird.  I would make it submit to a new action, like "set_current_user" which is a POST action.

in your login template:

```
<%= form_tag '/set_current_user' do %>
  <%= f.label "Name" %>
  <br/>
    <%= select_tag "user_id", options_for_select(@users.collect{|user| [user.name, user.id] } %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

in the controller (you'll need to amend routes.rb to make the '/set_current_user' go to this action) you then need to set something which will keep the user logged in.  The traditional way to do this is via `session[:user_id]`, and to have a method `current_user` which uses this.

```
def set_current_user
  session[:user_id] = params[:user_id]
  redirect_to "/" and return
end
```

Your initial approach is reminiscent of how this sort of thing is normally handled, wherein you **do** have a form_for, but it's for a UserSession object rather than a User object.